# Corrupted .so file centos 7

Tags: centos, boot, libraries

I boot my centos 7 in normal mode and when I try to login without asking password says login incorrect, after I boot in single mode and in boot log I see this error on during boot: `/usr/sbin/sulogin: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libfreebl3.so: file too short Authorization not available. check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information`
and after that I can't even login in single mode How can I solve it?

Comment: This is on a fresh install? Can you reproduce? Possibly a bad sector of disk corruption from hardware fault?

Comment: @JamesRisner No it's not fresh installed and it's installed on esxi and some times before the hard was full and after that I free up some space but can't login because of the said problem

Comment: That library, I believe, is nss related. Wonder if an update got only some files installed when the hard drive was full?

Comment: @JamesRisner Yes I think this will make the problem, so How can I fix it?